# Imageview image change while hover, Javafx

Tags: css, button, javafx, imageview

I want to change image set on imageview through css while hover it. Imageview is set on button and while hovering the button the background color will change. Now I need to change image too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign a style-class to your button and then in your style-sheet add a new style :

```
.my-button {
    -fx-graphic: url("abc.png");
}

.my-button:hover {
    -fx-graphic: url("xyz.png");
}
```

where,

- **abc.png** -> Image present on the button
- **xyz.png** -> New Image to be shown on hover
- **.my-button** -> Style Class assigned to the button

Comment: And is it possible to set size of an image?

Comment: No, you cannot set the size of the image using css. You can however do the same using Java code.